# What counts as passing on a treasure room?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

On the character page, it says I have to "pass on 2 treasure rooms" in order to unlock Samson.  If I enter the treasure room, but do not pick up the item, does that count as passing on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it does, I've just unlocked Samson and I've entered every treasure room along the way, choosing not to pick up Cupid's Arrow and Telepathy for Dummies.